# Invalid incremental change record with Android Studio's Instant Run

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0, android-instant-run

When building my app I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug'.
java.io.IOException: Invalid incremental change record : CHANGED,C:\Users\gingo\Documents\Dropbox (SKOUMAL, s.r.o.)\work\myproject\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRun\debug\folders\4000\5\enhanced\com\android\tools\fd\runtime\AppPatchesLoaderImpl.class
```

The only way to get rid of it is `Build -> Rebuild project`.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is `,` (comma) in project path. Simply remove it and you are good to go.

Let me explain it little bit deeply. The reason could be found in [`ChangeRecords.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/transforms/ChangeRecords.java) file. In method `load(File file)` it parses some change records from file and it uses `,` (comma) as divider for line-fields. See the whole code of method:

```
/**
 * Load change records from a persisted file.
 */
@NonNull
static ChangeRecords load(File file) throws IOException {
    ChangeRecords changeRecords = new ChangeRecords();
    List<String> rawRecords = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
    for (String rawRecord : rawRecords) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(rawRecord, ",");
        if (st.countTokens() != 2) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid incremental change record : " + rawRecord);
        }
        changeRecords.add(Status.valueOf(st.nextToken()), st.nextToken());
    }
    return changeRecords;
}
```